# Compilation Error - Namespace not found when it is present in my references and bin

Tags: c#, asp.net, server, hosting

I am receiving a compilation error on my ASP.NET webforms application stating that the namespace for iTextSharp is not found. The reference for this is present and it is also present in my bin folder. The application works fine locally but this has only occurred when I have gone to host my application.

I have tried changing the target environment and also uninstalling and then reinstalling the package but this doesn't fix the problem.

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Compilation Error
Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource 
required to service this request. Please review the following specific 
error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'iTextSharp' 
could 
not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly 
reference?)

Source Error:


Line 9:  using System.Configuration;
Line 10: using System.IO;
Line 11: using iTextSharp.text;
Line 12: using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
Line 13: 

Source File: 
c:\inetpub\websites\LocalUser\

px.cs    Line: 11 


Show Detailed Compiler Output:

Show Complete Compilation Source:


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET 
Version:4.0.30319.36480
```